# Can I have both RBS enabled and plain Content DBs on the same SharePoint 2010 farm?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, rbs

As RBS is enabled at the scope of the content database, can I have both RBS enabled and plain Content DBs on the same SharePoint 2010 farm? I know the answer is Yes. But do we face any issues in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install RBS for SharePoint you create an RBS BLOB and enable support for it at the content database level.  So if you only enable support for some content databases then the rest of them will continue to operate without RBS.

I dont see any issue in mix environment , in term of performance or integration etc, Rather you need maintain two type of DBs. Different backup strategy for each type of DB(its depend upon the method of backup you have), recovery plan and  these kind of admin issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and no you shouldn't face any issues.